# How to search an array of strings in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am very new in the world of C++ so if I do not ask the question correctly I apologize in advance.

I have a homework that I am trying to complete in C++. It has multiple tasks that needs to be completed. Here are the tasks: 1) Extract names from a text file. 2) display them(unsorted) 3) display them again(sorted) 4) search through the list and find names starting with same alphabets and count them and display them.

I have been able to do number 1 through 3 without much issue. But I am stumped on how to search through an array of strings and find names with same alphabets to count and display them? Please keep in mind I am very new to C++ and would like a nudge in the right direction to get this sorted!!!

Okay, so i was able to create a function to sort the names

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void selectionSort(string[], int);
void showNames(const string[], int);
void extractNames(string[], int);
bool searchForNames(string[], int);
int binarySearch(const string[], int, char);

int main()
{

const int NUM_NAMES = 20;
string names[NUM_NAMES];


ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("names.txt");

outputFile << "Collins, Bill" << endl;
outputFile << "Smith, Bart" << endl;
outputFile << "Allen, Jim" << endl;
outputFile << "Griffin, Jim" << endl;
outputFile << "Stamey, Marty" << endl;
outputFile << "Rose, Geri" << endl;
outputFile << "Taylor, Terry" << endl;
outputFile << "Johnson, Jill" << endl;
outputFile << "Allison, Jeff" << endl;
outputFile << "Looney, Joe" << endl;
outputFile << "Wolfe, Bill" << endl;
outputFile << "James, Jean" << endl;
outputFile << "Weaver, Jim" << endl;
outputFile << "Pore, Bob" << endl;
outputFile << "Rutherford, Greg" << endl;
outputFile << "Javens, Cathy" << endl;
outputFile << "Pike, Gordon" << endl;
outputFile << "Holland, Beth" << endl;

outputFile.close();

//call function that extracts names from the text file and assigns them to
//an array of names so it can be manuplated later
extractNames(names, NUM_NAMES);


//Display names in unsorted order
cout << "Unsorted names are: " << endl;
cout << "------------------- " << endl;
showNames(names, NUM_NAMES);

cout << endl;
cout << endl;

//Sort the names
selectionSort(names, NUM_NAMES);

//Display names in sorted order
cout << "Sorted names are: " << endl;
cout << "----------------- " << endl;
showNames(names, NUM_NAMES);

cout << endl;


searchForNames(names, NUM_NAMES);

}

void showNames(const string array[], int size)
{
    for(int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        cout << array[count] << endl;
}

void selectionSort(string array[], int size)
{
    int startScan;
    string MinValue;
    int minIndex;
    for(startScan=0; startScan < (size-1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex=startScan;
    MinValue = array[startScan];
    for(int index=startScan+1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if(array[index]<MinValue)
        {
            MinValue = array[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }

    array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
    array[startScan] = MinValue;
}

}
void extractNames( string names[], int size)
 {
int count =0;
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("names.txt");
while(count<size && getline(inputFile, names[count]))
{
    count++;
}
inputFile.close();
}

bool searchForNames(string names[], int size)
{
    for (char value = 'A'; value < 'Z'; value++)
    {
        cout << "Names starting with " << value << " are: "<< endl;
         binarySearch(names, 20, value);
}
return true;
}
int binarySearch(const string array[], int elements, char value)
{
//string abc;
//abc=static_cast<string>(&value);
int first = 0, last = elements - 1, middle , position = -1;
bool found = false;
while(!found && first <= last)
{
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    if(array[middle] == &value)
    {
        found = true;
        position = middle;
    }
    else if(array[middle] > &value)
        last = middle - 1;
    else
        first = middle + 1;
}

return position;
}
```

I am still not able to do this though: Create a function to count how many last names begin with each letter and output the names and the total number of names each time. This function should be passed the array by value and the size of the array by value. The function should output the names that begin with a particular letter then output the total number of names. Do NOT output results for letters that do not have any names, i.e. for example ther are no names that begin with B, so no output should be generated for this letter. This is my first time asking a question in StackOverflow so if I cannot explain it correctly I apologize.

Comment: So what does your code look like so far?

Comment: Have you looked at the `substr` command for `string`?

Comment: they are sorted. can't you just find first A, then first B, and qtyOfA = positionFirstB - positionFirstA ? and so on for each letter

Comment: this question has many elements. what are you specifically struggling with

Comment: is the first letter of the last name the first character of the string?

Comment: i don't know how to add my source code here yet so i just made changes to the original code. It looks very off, I guess I am just trying to figure out how pass the value of the array named names in a way so i can search for the right alphabet. that is why i tried to type cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic first C++ assignment, and I gather that it's to get you used to the various tools available in the Standard Template Library.

Firstly, sorting. There is a function in the `<algorithm>` header called `std::sort` that will do this for you. Check out this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to learn a little more about it. It will seriously ease your pain.

For searching, try [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Next you want a lookup that keep letters (`chars`) and a count of how many times each one occurs as the first letter of a name. An [`std::map<char, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a class that does this for you. A simple for loop with `char_count[name[0]]++;`, where `char_count` is a map, is likely what you want.

Comment: <algorith> header and STL library tools sounds pretty fantastic to me right about now unfortunately i cannot use it since technically "I have not learned it yet". So I have to use good old long method of sorting and searching. Hence, the question.

Comment: my question is: how to search for the fist character in a string array? do i have to use type casting to accomplish any of this?

Comment: `std::string` defines `operator[]`, so if you're doing a linear search then just loop through the array and check the return of `str[0]`, where `str` is your string.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find all the matches it might just be simpler to search linearly through the array rather then using a binary algorithm. This approach is Slower but easier to implement and get your head around if your new to C++.

As you traverse the array you can build up an array of matches and return that.

Comment: can I use linear search in a way that if what I am looking for has multiple entries, the search will find the multiple items instead of stopping after encountering it the first time?

Comment: Yes just interate over the entire list. When you find an answer append it to a list of matches. At the end of the interaction return the list.

Comment: So, my inexperience with C++ is forcing me to ask this question. Do I need to type cast the string array to a char(is that even possible?)? otherwise how would the search look for the first character of the string?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand step 4 correctly, if you have a list like ("Andrew", "Ann", "Dave", "Dominic", "Don"), you want to output something like: 2 A, 3 D. Correct?

If that's the case, then you simply need to loop through your sorted list examining the first character of each string.  If it's the same as the previous character, increase the count.  If it's not, output the previous character and reset the count.  A little special handing for the start and end of your looping and you're done.

BTW, I don't see a need for the binary search, or is there more to this assignment?

Comment: nope, just what you see. I was battling that argument with myself but then settled for binary since it is supposed to be more "efficient"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works

```
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> resultsPerLetter(26);
  for (int i = 0; i<elements; ++i) {
      resultsPerLetter[tolower(names[i][0]) - 'a'].push_back(names[i]);
      }

  for (int i = 0; i<26 ; ++i) {
      if (resultsPerLetter[i].size()!=0) {
          std::cout<<"number of names starting with '"<<char(i+'a')<<"' : " << resultsPerLetter[i].size() << "\n";
          std::cout<<"The names : \n";
          for(int j = 0, j_e = resultsPerLetter[i].size(); j<e; ++j) {
               std::cout << " - " << resultsPerLetter[i][j] << "\n";
               }
          }
     }
```